# Documentum Rest api problems

Tags: api, documentum

I tried finding out the rest api for documentum but not able to find that.
Anyone know how to download documentum rest api in server ?
Do we need any platform to deploy these api ?

Comment: Your question is not suited for SO site. However, REST API can be downloaded from OpenText support site, and only there. It's an web application and you need to deploy it on Tomcat or your application server of choice and enable access to Documentum repository.

Comment: @Miki  ..I tried installing from opentext but it is showing you are not authorized to use these service .Could you please let me know how to download API and I am working for a client who is using documentum as DB in their machines.

Comment: @YatinRana for deploying the application you should have the access to application server. For your case you need to ask client to install the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Miki suggested you need to connect to Opentext Support for the same. The application needs to be receive from the Vendor and need to be deployed in the Documentum application server.